# Unreal Engine 5 Setup problem with Openssl library

Tags: c++, openssl, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Unreal engine 5 has v1 version of openssl library with it. I checked in its third part folder. I was able to use it inside my plugin by adding it directly to the dependency modules. However I wanted to use the newer version of openssl to be precise https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/openssl-3.1.0
I made an x64 build for which the bin lib and include folders got generated along with dlls.
I imported it into my project inside OpenSSL3 folder
Post these I was getting decrepitated warning for multiple functions which I assumed to be correct installation.
I added the following lines to Build.cs file

```
if (Target.Platform.IsInGroup(UnrealPlatformGroup.Windows))
{
 PublicIncludePaths.AddRange(
 new string[] {
 Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "ThirdParty/OpenSSL3/include")
      }
   );

 PublicAdditionalLibraries.AddRange(
 new string[] {
 Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "ThirdParty/OpenSSL3/lib/libcrypto.lib"),
 Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "ThirdParty/OpenSSL3/lib/libssl.lib"),
 }
   );
 
 PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("libcrypto-3-x64.dll");
 PublicDelayLoadDLLs.Add("libssl-3-x64.dll");
}
```

```
The build becomes a success however I am getting crashes as well as test case failure that suggests that the setup was not complete or correct.
Kindly help with any information regarding the same.
Error message:-
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: 
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: Fatal error!
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: 
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: Unhandled Exception: 0xc06d007e
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: 
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc96a2cd29 KERNELBASE.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbfc8db784 UnrealEditor-<Plugin>.dll!__delayLoadHelper2() [D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\delayimp\delayhlp.cpp:312]
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbfc8d9d92 UnrealEditor-<Plugin>.dll!_tailMerge_libcrypto_3_x64_dll() []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbfc8d8e57 UnrealEditor-<Plugin>.dll!UMessageDigestLibrary::MD4Hash() [C:\Utils\UnrealProject\Test\Plugins\<Plugin>\Source\<Plugin>\Private\Library\MessageDigestLibrary.cpp:57]
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbfc8d9941 UnrealEditor-<Plugin>.dll!MessageDigestTest::RunTest() [C:\Utils\UnrealProject\Test\Plugins\<Plugin>\Source\<Plugin>\Tests\MessageDigestTest.cpp:10]
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc35491cb2 UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc354a4888 UnrealEditor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf97eaefd UnrealEditor-AutomationWorker.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf97e9c34 UnrealEditor-AutomationWorker.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffbf97ee656 UnrealEditor-AutomationWorker.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff6900ea810 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff69010287d UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff69010296a UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff690105680 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff6901171b4 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff69011a516 UnrealEditor.exe!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc99007614 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffc992e26a1 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2023.03.19-11.45.48:226][305]LogWindows: Error:
```

The line where it says error

`EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();` 
Thanks a lot in advance

I tried to rebuild the open ssl library again.
Searched for the possible solution related to the error code however could not find any related result that directly points to the solution.
Rebuild the project.
Tried to run test cases with various other implementations.

Comment: I have also tried to generate a static build however it still did not work. To be precise I just want it to work I am not exclusively looking for a dynamic library to work. I am ok if a solution exists with the static build.